# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repository'

Tags: java, apache

I am facing this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a 
-----
-----
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.deck.microFin.entity.UserMstr
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210)
```

Below is my repository Java class:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<CompanyMstr, Long> {
```

And my entity class is this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "user_mstr", schema = "admin")
@XmlRootElement
public class UserMstr implements Serializable {
```

What am I missing?

Comment: An `@Entity` annotation on `UserMstr`.

Comment: @daniu now i solve it out by change Entity,change mappedSuperClass to Entity.